# how to set focus in textbox after responsePage in wicket 7?

Tags: wicket, wicket-7

I want to set focus to specific component after I go back to my FirstPage..

```
PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
setResponsePage(new SecondPage(pageParameters) {
            @Override
            public void doSelect(Integer ID) {                
                setResponsePage(FirstPage.this);
                // set focus to spesific component here

            }

            @Override
            public void doCancel() {
                setResponsePage(FirstPage.this);
            }
        });
```

Please help me..

Comment: You're not allowed to hold a reference from one page to another, please use a PageReference instead.

Answer (score 3):

IMO I could choose HTML5 for this . In HTML there's an [autofocus](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control) attribute to all form fields.

You can decide while page loading which component to be focus.In your case it is the default constructor . Have some criteria and focus on particular component if you are focus the component dynamically otherwise do like below . No Need of Javascript.

```
TextField textField = new TextField("name");
textField.add(new AttributeModifier("autofocus",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a little JavaScript to your page, search for FocusOnLoadBehavior:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Request+Focus+on+a+Specific+Form+Component

Comment: i can't find AbstractBehavior class.. i think we can't using that way because  It uses the old wicket version..

Comment: IIRC they changed it to `Behavior` (which is an `abstract` class). See here :https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AbstractBehavior.html